# Foundation for humanity with dignity, respect and liberty

Tags: sentence-construction

Does any of the following grammatically make sense? How would you write it otherwise?

- “We believe a stable home is the foundation for humanity with respect, liberty and dignity.”

Or

- “We believe ...foundation for humanity in respect, liberty and dignity.”

It’s the three values (respect, dignity, liberty) in humanity I want to emphasis that my stable home will promote.

Comment: I think the word 'humanity' is a bit distracting here. Is it possible that you are referring to individual human lives rather than the human race as a whole? If so, how about changing "humanity" to "a life"?

Comment: Or alternatively, are you referring to the quality of humaneness?